# How to add svg icon to TextView with default text font?

Tags: android, svg, fonts, textview

here is my custom text view:

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    public CustomTextView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        setCustomFont(ctx);
    }

    public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx) {

        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "icons/svg_icons.ttf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        setTypeface(tf);
        return true;
    }
}
```

my icon code is :

```
<string name="svg_warning" translatable="false">&#xe900;</string>
```

I'm adding svg icon to TextView with text by this:

```
mytextview.setText(String.format("Please Select a Country %s",getResources().getString(R.string.svg_warning)));
```

**But font of "Please Select a Country" is not the same like default Android font. How to add svg icon to TextView with default Android's text font?**

Result:
[image]

Comment: holy shit i never knew textviews supported svg like this!

Answer (score 1):

holy shit i never knew textviews supported svg like this!

As I can see from your code your customTextView will have the Typeface you just set in the setCustomFont method. What you can do is have 2 textviews, one your customTextView for the svg and left to it enclosed in a horizontal LinearLayout a normal TextView. You can't have one font to some text in a textview and another font for the rest of the text, in web can you have 2 different fonts for a p tag?

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <CustomTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it's not best solution because,  I have in other screens more icons on text view, it will not solve this case

Comment: @NickUnuchek like I said you cannot have 2 different typefaces in a the same textView, I don't know how else to put this